# Excel VBA: Run-Time error 1004 calling Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have found different Run-Time Error 1004 questions, but none of them were totally appropriate.

I get an error 1004 "Application-defined or object defined error" when using workbooks (last Row).

```
Dim mainWB  As Workbook
Dim mainWS  As Worksheet
Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim WBname As String

For Each wb In Workbooks
            If Left(wb.Name, 4) = "D_SO" And Len(wb.Name) > 30 Then
                WBname = wb.Name
                Exit For
            End If
Next

mainWB.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1600, 300)).Value = Workbooks(WBname).Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1600, 300)).Value
```

None of my Workbooks objects in the last row seem to be working, eventhough the names are right. Can you find my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `Range object` reference of that type: `Range(LeftTopCell, RightBottomCell)` you have to care of what is in fact inside parenthesis.

In your situation you have always `Activesheet cells` which is not what you want to have. Therefore you have to have full reference to cells in this way:

```
mainWB.Sheets(1).Range(mainWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), _
                       mainWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1600, 300)).Value = 
        Workbooks(WBname).Sheets(1).Range(Workbooks(WBname).Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), _ 
                                     Workbooks(WBname).Sheets(1).Cells(1600, 300)).Value
```

To make it shorter you could think of using `Range.Copy` method instead.

Comment: Wouldn t have thought about that thanks! 
I have Range.Copy still would give me the same issue though, as I want to copy from the non active Sheet and my 1600 and 300 are actually variable (I cannot just write "A1:CZ1600")